# How to add number of days in date field using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day); 
$('#input').val(today);
```

I have this working piece of code where I would like to change the value based on a variable.
For example, I want to have a
variable a = today + 365 days, that should update input value set to 365 days ahead from today.
Variable b = today + 650 days, that should update input value set to 650 days ahead from today.

I have tried  the following but cant get it to work

```js
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
var a = (today + (365 * 60 * 1000));
var b = (today + (650 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
$('#input1').val(a);
$('#input2').val(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `today`'s value is going to be the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z. Adding `365*60*1000` gets you 365 *minutes* later.

Comment: Thanks! @HereticMonkey
However, is my code look functional? I think there might be error in my code and hence it's not working. I am not concerned about the number of days calculation, rather syntax error.

Comment: No, because `today` is a string, so you're producing a string based on `now`, then concatenating a number to it. Just change `today` to `now` in the definition of `a` and `b`, then use `.toLocaleString([], { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' })` to get the date values as string (see [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/215552) for more)